# I can only see one blog post in wordpress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

I have transferred my WordPress blog from Godaddy to my own personal server and it works OK, but I wanted to edit some of my blog posts and I can't. When I go into my blog posts page I can only see the most recent post, but the other posts are still showing in the public environment. I don't know what other information I could give you, so just ask and I will try to provide. Thanks.

[Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing](http://cl.ly/3h47362T2E3E110p0R1R).

Please help.

Comment: Good question but I think  better suited for prorammers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the solution. I disabled all of my plugins and enabled each one at a time. I found that the Google Analytics Dashboard plugin was culprit.